# JsonMappingException while PATCHing to a Spring Data REST Repository

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to PATCH an object, that has a OneToOne relationship to another polymorphic object. The object owning the relationship looks like this (I've omitted irrelevant JPA annotations and fields):

```
public class Policy extends BaseEntity {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHANNELFLOW_ID")
    private ChannelFlowConfig channelFlow;
}
```

The referenced object looks like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "CHANNELFLOWCONFIG")
public abstract class ChannelFlowConfig extends BaseEntity {
        @JsonProperty("type")
        public String getType() {
            return getClass().getName();
        }
}
```

The child objects have nothing special, just some different fields (again, fields are omitted above), they have no Repository but instead are all handled via the PolicyRepository.
Now when I'm trying to PATCH a Policy with a body that has the exact same content retrieved from a GET on /policy/2, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class com.vw.mbbc.authserver.model.policy.ChannelFlowConfig)
at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.vw.mbbc.authserver.model.policy.Policy["channelFlow"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1376) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1197) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedUsingDefaultImpl(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:165) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:105) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:209) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:502) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:104) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:240) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1628) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1301) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.doMerge(DomainObjectReader.java:222) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.read(DomainObjectReader.java:77) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
```

This error occurs when PATCHing via CocoaRest AND when PATCHing via Retrofit. The interesting thing is that the client side (Retrofit) is able to deserialize the JSON correctly (Jackson versions are the same on client and server side).
The content sent looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    /* some fields */
    "channelFlow": {
        "id": 1,
        /* some fields */
        "type": "com.somepackage.VehicleChannelFlowConfig"
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Edit: Even when I register an ObjectMapper in my server manually, it is able to deserialize the JSON. I'm out of ideas now :-(

Edit #2:
The problem is Spring's DomainObjectReader, the code

```
if (!mappedProperties.hasPersistentPropertyForField(fieldName)) {
    i.remove();
}
```

removes the correctly transmitted type annotation. This seems to be a problem with Spring itself, Jackson is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the Spring-Data version we're using (4.5.5), the DomainObjectReader was just throwing away any JSON properties that weren't persistent fields (which a type field obviously isn't). It was probably fixed by this commit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/4150688851323e54967cacfbcd0d6a7e00c41980 which did aim to include transient fields (not really the problem I was encountering, but a similar one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY)
public String getType() {
    return getClass().getName();
}
```

---

In my opinion `orphanRemoval = true` is redundant as you set only `PERSIST` and `MERGE` cascade types...

Comment: READ_ONLY sadly doesn't change anything :-(